# Does MySQL support interior mutability or sticky bit?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Say, I have a complex MySQL procedure. The procedure is basically a complex `SELECT` query that use data inside a table to output some records.

For convenience, the procedure need to write to a temporary table to calculate the final result.

So can I grant properly so that a user that can only read the database can call this procedure to get its output, although the procedure actually need to write to the database? Because essentially this procedure don't intend to write, it just cache some data to a specific table with a name start with underscore so it shouldn't break anything seriously, beside costing storage of disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A stored program or view that executes in definer security context executes with the privileges of the account named by its `DEFINER` attribute. These privileges may be entirely different from those of the invoking user.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html

As long as the user *defining* the procedure has the necessary permissions and doesn't explicitly force the procedure to run in `INVOKER` context, the permissions of the invoking user have no impact on what the procedure can do. The permissions of the *defining* user apply to the procedure's actions.

The invoking user only needs to be able to run it.  No special arrangements are necessary, because this is the default behavior.

The `DEFINER` defaults to the user creating the procedure. If that account has the `SUPER` privilege, they can actually declare a different definer account whose privileges will apply.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, stored procedures in MySQL operate with privileges associated with the procedure's definer, not the user who invokes the procedure, who only needs execute privilege on the procedure.

A stored procedure can be configured to run in invoker context, thus executing with same privilege as the invoking user, but this is not common.

Just make sure when you define the procedure the definer has appropriate permission to do everything that needs to be done during execution.